# Javascript generate logical array based on condition

Tags: javascript

Coming from a **matlab** background, I am trying to replicate the following scenario in **Javascript**

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
B = 4;
C = A == B;
answer => C = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

In other words, it generates a logical array where only the value compared is set to 1. I can do this using a loop but I was wondering if there a 1 liner solution to this in javascript?

Comment: No there is not. JavaScript is not that kind of programming language. There's the `.filter()` function on the Array prototype however. (Well `.map()`; not enough coffee yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the fanciest you could get would be

```
var C = A.map(function(v) { return v == B ? 1 : 0; });
```

That's supported in newer JavaScript runtime systems.

In JavaScript it'd probably be more idiomatic to prefer a result array containing boolean values:

```
var C = A.map(function(v) { return v == B; });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `map()` function to do something similar to what you were looking for:

```
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var B = 4;
var C = function (x) { return +(x === B); };
var answer = A.map(C);
```

<sub>`var C = x => +(x === B);` would look cleaner, but that's ES6 code (experimental).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There's not a one-liner, but using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can get you pretty close to what you want:

```
 var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 var b = 4;
 var c = a.map(function(item) { return item === b? 1: 0; });

 console.log(c);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7bgT/)

Note map isn't supported by older browsers, the MDN link above has polyfil code or you can include any number of libraries that provide something equivalent (e.g. jQuery has a [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the it is only supported in newer browsers

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function :

```
function equals(a, b) {
    var result = [];
    while (result.length < a.length) {
        result.push(+(a[result.length] == b));
    }
    return result;
}

var A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var B = 4;
var C = equals(A, B); // [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```